# How to connect from Phoenix/Elixir to Google Cloud Spanner or Google Cloud Bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, elixir, phoenix-framework, google-cloud-bigtable, google-cloud-spanner

I need to use **Elixir/Phoenix** and **Google Serverless DBs** for a realtime Forex App.

So how to connect from **Phoenix/Elixir** to **Google Cloud Spanner or Google Cloud Bigtable**? Any link for Doc or tutorial would be appreciated.

This question was first asked on [ElixirForum.](https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-connect-from-phoenix-elixir-to-google-cloud-spanner-or-google-cloud-bigtable/16564) and the answer suggested was [Elixir on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/elixir/), however, I have gone through all the materials on that link and found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclosure: I am a product manager for Google Cloud Bigtable.*

There's an [Elixir client for Cloud Spanner](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/elixir-google-api/tree/master/clients/spanner) you can take a look at.

There isn't a Google-written and maintained Elixir client for Cloud Bigtable yet, but there's Elixir support for a [number of other products](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/elixir-google-api/tree/master/clients) in the same repo as well.

However, there's a [third-party Elixir client for Cloud Bigtable](https://github.com/bzzt/bigtable) you can explore; please direct any questions to their GitHub repo.

That said, if you're looking for a true serverless database backend for your app, consider using [Google Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/), which has also has [Elixir support](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/elixir-google-api/tree/master/clients/firestore). Cloud Spanner and Cloud Bigtable require provisioning dedicated resources so there will be a minimum charge *regardless of usage*, while Cloud Firestore provides a pay-as-you-go model that will make it easy to scale from a small app to a large application.

Take a look at the pricing guides for each of these databases for more information:

- [Cloud Spanner pricing](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/pricing)
- [Cloud Bigtable pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/pricing)
- [Cloud Firestore pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing)

Comment: Google Cloud Spanner has an SQL API I 'm cool with. Imo Spanner is the best of both worlds (SQL and NoSQL). It would be excellent to have something like this https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/nodejs/ but for Elixir. Or is there a tutorial for that in your codelab or doc base?